# Use 2 different sortings in one query

Tags: mysql

Have mysql table like:
expiry_date | add_date.

Is it possible to sort it in the following way:

First I want to have all records with the expiry_date > now() sorted  descending by this expiry_date, and after this all other records sorted descending by add_date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN expiry_date > now() then expiry_date else add_date end) DESC
```

EDIT: try this:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN expiry_date > now() then expity_date  end) ADC ,add_date DESC
```

Comment: thanks. Is it possible to have expiry_date asc and add_date desc ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The only issue with the second answer is that records with expiry date > now i would like to have at the begining, and they are displayed at the end in the moment.